# Conditional table joins

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have following scope in my eloquent model and I want to add two conditions to it. I need help in doing it.

```
public function scopeImages($query) {
    $query->join('images as i', function ($join) {
        $join->on('i.vessel_id', '=', 'vessel.id')
        ->where('i.sort', '=', 'min(i.sort)');
    })
    ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'vessel.user_id')
    ->select('vessel.*', 'i.image as image', 'users.name as brokername');
}
```

`images` table has `featured` and `sort` columns. I want to select one row where `images.featured is 1` and `min sort` of the returned results. If there are no `images.featured=1` then I want to select `min of sort`.

Currently the above scope selects image of `min sort` for each `vessel_id`

Comment: Do you want to end up with one final row, or one row per image?

Comment: @Chris One row per vessel

Answer (score 0):

If you order by featured (if featured is boolean) in desc and sort in asc, it will list featured 1 in highest priority and then list sort from min to max. Now, if you take 1st row, you will get what you want.

```
$query->join('images', 'images.vessel_id', '=', 'vessel.id')
        ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id' ,'=', 'vessel.user_id')
        ->select('vessel.*', 'images.image as image', 'users.name as brokername')
        ->orderBy('images.featured', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('images.sort', 'ASC')
        ->take(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I'm trying to do is, for every `image.vessel_id=vessel.id` I want to `where images.sort=min(images.sort)`. Example, see the raw query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588142/mysql-left-join-min

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated subquery

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

```
    SELECT  v.*, 
(SELECT `image` FROM images WHERE vessel_id = v.id ORDER BY featured DESC, sort LIMIT 1) AS image
    FROM `vessel` AS v
```

@EDIT
You Can give this a try:

```
public function scopeImages($query) {
    return $query
        ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'vessel.user_id')
        ->select(\DB::raw("vessel.*, (SELECT `image` FROM images WHERE vessel_id = vessel.id ORDER BY featured DESC, sort LIMIT 1) AS image, users.name as brokername"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ad4s I want this written in Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: I edited my answer. I didn't test this in framework. It's also quick-and-dirty. Sometimes it's last resort, but I could live with it ;)