# Laravel Database Query Builder Relationships

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `products` and `product_image` tables. In my `product_image` table I have a foreign key: `product_id`.

What I want is to get only 1 image of each product in my table the best example here will be e-commerce website in which they have all list of products with only 1 image to show, that's what I'm planning to do with my code.

But the problem in my code is the output of my product lists will depend on how many images they have.

for example:

- product 1 has 2 images
- product 2 has 1 image
- product 3 has 3 images

the output of my code will be

*product 1, product 1, product 2, product 3, product 3, product 3*

**I have this code in laravel**

```php
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('product_name','like',escape_like($request->search_product).'%')
        ->orderBy('product_name','asc')
        ->join('product_image','products.id','=','product_image.product_id')
        ->select('products.*','product_image.*')
        ->paginate($request->total_products);
```

**I have this code in Vue**

```html
<div class="col-md-4" v-for="product in products">
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <img class="card-img-top" :src="product.path" alt="Product Image">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.product_name }}</h5>
                <div class="card-text">
                    <p v-if="product.status == 'Sale'" class="old-price float-right"><del>Php. {{ product.price.toFixed(2) }}</del> </p>
                    <p >Php. {{ product.price.toFixed(2) }}</p>

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" title="Edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make your life easier and create a `Product` model with an `images` relationship. If you use joins, you’re going to get the same product back for each image (i.e. a product has three images, you’ll get the product three times). If you use a model and relations, you’ll get a single product with the three images under an `image` key; you can then grab the first one in your Vue component to use as the main image.

Comment: @rinru just to be clear: the example output that you included in your question is your desired output? or that is the issue?

Comment: @MartinBean You mean i must used laravel eloquent relationship? If yes, I'm planning not to use eloquent with this matter.

Comment: @HCK the example output is the issue of my code.

Comment: @rinru do you have a particular reason not to use Eloquent?

Comment: @HCK I just want to practice joining tables or creating relationships without using eloquent, But don't get me wrong eloquent is good I've tried it but for this matter I just want to use query builders.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317227/left-join-to-get-a-single-row-in-laravel